# Adding javascript to php header

Tags: php, javascript

Hi I am working on a website for uni for an online store.
I am using NOP Design freecart and everything works fine.

I have the menu and header in PHP which work fine but I can't get my javascript which displays items in cart and total in the php menu

PHP Header

```
    <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html">Pet Accessories</a></h1> 

    <!-- Cart -->
    <div id="cart">
        <a href="managecart.html" class="cart-link" >Your Shopping Cart</a>
        <br>


    </div>
    <!-- End Cart -->

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Navigation -->
```

The javascript I want to use

scart.js file

```
if ( Cart_is_empty()) {
document.write('Your cart is empty.');
   } else {
      document.write('In your cart:<p>');
      Print_total_products(true);
      document.write(', ');
      Print_total(true);
      document.write('<p>Applicable shipping and taxes extra.<p>');
      document.write('<a href="managecart.html">View Cart</a>');
```

}

If I paste that code into my index.html file is displays correctly but when I paste it into the .php file it doesnt work

I've tried pasting this 
    `<?php echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/scart.js\"></script>; ?> ))`
into the `header.php` file but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas on what I should be doing? The shopping cart code I have used from a site so it is quite tricky for me to get my head around.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Piece of advice:  ignore what they teach you at uni and instead pick up a good book on JS and/or visit sites like this one where you can learn to code with proper techniques.  ;)

Comment: Why wrap it in php tags anyway if it's just a template file?

Comment: Show us the outputted header section where the jscript file is supposed to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/scart.js'></script>"; ?>`

be sure the file path is right

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have posted

```
<?php echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/scart.js\"></script>; ?> ))
```

This is not valid PHP. You never close the quotes. Besides, the `))` seem misplaced as well. As other people say, try this:

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scart.js"></script>'; ?>
```

As some of the comments point out you should have a particular reason to place this in PHP as opposed to directly in the HTML, like so:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scart.js"></script>
    <?php
        //more php...
    ?>
</head>
```

There is no reason to wrap it in PHP if you don't add it programatically.

Comment: The reason that I wanted it in the header of my site template is so that you can see the items and total cost no matter what page you are on the site. The assignment brief wanted us to use PHP for the left menu and header.

Comment: I wanted it like this so that you can see the cart items and cost no matter what page you are on within the site

Comment: Thanks, it's now just a formatting problem to get it to appear in the right spot